# Use Actionbarsherlock in Program

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i use "Actionbarsherlock" in my project 
First i import "Actionbarsherlock" in my project then delete folder "libs"

### But my question is how can I change the code below؟

mainactivity

```
   package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

   import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
   import android.app.ActionBar;
   import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
   import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
   import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "water"," time" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}}
```

---

MoviesFragment

```
   package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

   import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.R;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;

   public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies,container,false);

    return rootView;
}

    }
```

---

GamesFragment

```
     package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

     import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.R;
      import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;

     public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container,false);

    return rootView;
    }}
```

---

TabsPagerAdapte

```
     package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

     import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.GamesFragment;
     import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MoviesFragment;


    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

  public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

 public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
     super(fm);
 }

 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {

    case 0:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new GamesFragment();
    case 1:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new MoviesFragment();

    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 2;
  }}
```

---

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

bro remove your email adress from the question.Now coming to your question your actionbar should be an object of supportActionbar.Change the getActionBar() to getSupportActionBar()l.And secondly,your main activity should extend sherlockActivity.Lastly,change the importation from the android actionbar to the sherlock actionbar